# Use my function in itself and return in 'correct' order

Tags: javascript, function

I have this function

```
var foo = function(){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    console.log(args[i]);
  }
};
```

that's used like this

```
foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
```

It's outcome

[image]

But I want it's usage to work like this, and get the same outcome

```
foo(1, 2, foo(3, 4, 5), 6, 7, 8);
```

Yet the out come for this is

[image]

Thanks in advance

Mach

Comment: Check the answer of T.J. Crowder. I added a comment of jsfiddle of that answer to make it clear. He is absoulutely right.

Comment: @shree202: Thanks for that. Note that the answer did already have a live example in it (using jsbin, rather than jsfiddle). Maybe I should make it more obvious how you see the source, I'll go do that...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ohh.. Sorry..  I didnt notice that, sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I want it's usage to work like this, and get the same outcome
>
> ```
> foo(1, 2, foo(3, 4, 5), 6, 7, 8);
> ```

You can't. That line is equivalent to this:

```
var tmp = foo(3, 4, 5);
foo(1, 2, tmp, 6, 7, 8);
```

That is, *first* the `foo(3, 4, 5)` bit runs, and then the `foo(1, 2, mumble, 6, 7, 8)` bit runs.

There are games you can play to defer execution, but they will tend to be very specific to what you're actually doing (which I assume isn't just outputting numbers in order).

For instance, a game you could play here would be to have `foo` detect whether its arguments are functions and, if so, call them; then you could use [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) (or similar) to create functions that, when called, will have the arguments you want. That looks like this:

```
var foo = function(){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  var arg;

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    arg = args[i];
    if (typeof arg === "function") {
        arg();
    } else {
        console.log(arg);
    }
  }
};
```

and then used like this:

```
foo(1, 2, foo.bind(undefined, 3, 4, 5), 6, 7, 8);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/witezizo/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/witezizo/1/edit))

That works because `Function#bind` doesn't call the function, it creates a *new* function that, when called, will get called with the arguments you gave `bind` (the first argument is what `this` will be during the call; if you don't have anything specific it needs to be, use `undefined` or `null`). So in effect when we do this:

```
foo(1, 2, foo.bind(undefined, 3, 4, 5), 6, 7, 8);
```

...we're doing this:

```
var tmpFunction = foo.bind(undefined, 3, 4, 5);
foo(1, 2, tmpFunction, 6, 7, 8);
```

(`Function#bind` is an ES5 feature present in all modern browsers except IE8 (which while not "modern" is still in significant use), but it can be correctly "shimmed" using es5-shim or similiar.)

(Trivia: This thing where you create a function with some of its arguments "baked into" it is called [*currying*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) a function, so named after the mathematician [Haskell Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry). [And yes, that's where the programming language Haskell gets *its* name.])

Comment: Great answer thanks. Your right I wasn't going to count in the console :P

I'm trying to make a function to make console.group a bit neater and faster, moved example to jsfidd

http://jsfiddle.net/988nP/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're calling **foo(3,4,5)** and putting it's return value to the second call to foo(...). Your code can be written as:

```
var ret = foo(3,4,5);
foo(1, 2, ret, 6, 7, 8);
```

I am unaware what console.log accepts as arguments, but if it can handle a function, you could do:

```
var func = function() { foo(3, 4, 5); };
foo(1, 2, func, 6, 7, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to return the args in your foo() as so:

```
var foo = function(){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    console.log(args[i]);
  }
  return args;
};
```

But, even so you would get an Array as the 3rd element of your array when you call:

```
foo(1, 2, foo(3, 4, 5), 6, 7, 8);
```

You will have to filter your arguments so if there's an array found among your arguments, you should split that into scalars and then pass them to the *slice* method.

Hope this helped, keep me posted.